# How to acces the it Object from Jersey in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jersey-1.0

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public Response getJSPPage(@PathParam("page") String page, @PathParam("get") String get){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //TODO: Informieren     
    map.put("url", "127.0.0.1");


    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/test", map)).build();
}
```

I can access the `url` in my jsp file with `${it.url}`, but how can I access it in the java part in my jsp file?

```
<%
    string url = it.url
%>
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Don't use scriptlets.

Comment: (`it` should be a request attribute.)